# iOS Notification observer Unit Test (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, tdd

I would like to write unit tests for my class that is registered as observer for few notifications. Is there any best approach, how to write and how to write them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your test doesn't create other objects that listen to those same notifications:

- Create an instance of your class
- Fire off a notification
- Confirm the expected results

I show this technique in a screencast: [How to TDD Model-View-Controller in iOS](https://qualitycoding.org/mvc-tdd/)

Comment: Your screencast is superb! Thank you. But I found out that my problem is elsewhere. I have a static library in which my controller is and that is the reason why Iam unable to test anything related to controllers view. Currently I have 3 targets in my app - App, Library and Test. From what I've learned during last few days best approach is to create another app that is dependent on my library and write test there... Or do you have any better suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Isn't the static library used by your app? So you ought to be able to write tests with the app as your test host. You probably don't need a separate test app.